# Regex for single delimiter between two patterns

Tags: regex, pcre

Given an input like `@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=C1@2=C2@3=C3>>@1=D1@2=D2@3=D3`, I want to match @2=A2 and @2=B2 such that there is only one `>>` between them.

I tried the regex  `(?!@2=A2.*>>.*>>.*@2=B2)@2=A2@.*>>.*@2=B2`.

This correctly identifies input like 
`@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=C1@2=C2@3=C3>>@1=D1@2=D2@3=D3` and also ignores the input 
`@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=C1@2=C2@3=C3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=D1@2=D2@3=D3`(@2=B2 comes after @2=A2 but @2=C2 is in between.).

However, it fails on inputs like `@1=A1@2=A2@3=A3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=B1@2=B2@3=B3>>@1=D1@2=D2@3=D3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
@2=A2[^>]*>>[^>]*@2=B2
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dybgMa/2)

**Explanation:**

```
@2=A2       # literally
[^>]*       # 0 or more any character that is not >
>>          # literally
[^>]*       # 0 or more any character that is not >
@2=B2       # literally
```

Comment: It works fine. Can you please explain why it works if you have time. I will accept it none the less after 2 mins.

Comment: @mohit: I've added explanation.